# Two weeks future date from calendar selenium ide

Tags: firefox, selenium, calendar, automation, ide

I am using Selenium IDE plugin and I want to select a future date which is 14 days from  today's date. The only way I can do that is using the calendar pop-up. I have used a variable to store setdate+14 function, but I am unable to understand how can I used this date to choose from the calender?

Also, how can I navigate to next month when the current date is more than 16/ 17th of the current month.

Thanks